# how do I make a select which always returns zero rows

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to determine if a column exists in a table for any jdbc driver.

In order to know the columns in a table, I have to make a query to the table and then get the ResultSetMetaData for the info, but this is pretty expensive in like 99% of times.

In mysql I have:

`SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 0,0`

In Intersystems caché I have:

`SELECT TOP 0 * FROM tablename`

But, for example, in JavaDB I cannot apply any limit at all.

Is there any generic query that would give me the same result and still be fair with the DB performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 'You' = 'Smart'
```

Comment: I would have said WHERE "Paula Bean" = "Brillant", but this works, too.

Comment: isn't it better to do: 'You' = 'Smart'  ?

Comment: Doing a select is unnecessary as you can query the database table metainfo without it.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. This can return the meta-data for any query.. Database metainfo can only return you the meta-data for an explicit single table.

Answer (score 17):

...or you could just use the DatabaseMetaData route.

There's a "getColumns" method that does what you need without creating a resultset.

Answer (score 9):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1 = 2;

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from tablename where 1 != 1
```

Comment: On some databases, 1 would refer to the *first column*.  Even so, this will work: not even NULL is not equal to NULL.

Comment: <> and != are fairly mutually exclusive across DBMS platforms, so I'd avoind inequality altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated, but if you just need the columns in MySQL, you can run SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename.  This returns columns and the associated info.